# Add a new item to a list of dictionaries and increase the item value for duplicate items

Tags: python

I want to count ARP reply packet using python.
Assume that I have the list

`list=[{"ipdst":"192.168.1.1","macdst":"aa:aa:aa","ipsrc":"192.168.1.2",count:1},
{"ipdst":"192.168.1.4","macdst":"cc:cc:cc","ipsrc":"192.168.1.5",count:1}`

and I want to add an item which has a different ipdst, macdst, and ipsrc in my list (for a new packet that has not been recorded in the list). If there is a packet with the same ipdst, macdst and ipsrc in the list I want to add count +1 because I want to count how many packets from the destination is sent to the source.
I've tried

```
for item in list 
    if item["ipdst"]==dst and item["macdst"]==mac and item["ipsrc"]=src:
        item["count"]+=1
    else 
        list.append(["ipdst"]==dst,["macdst"]==mac,["ipsrc"]==src
```

but the output is

```
    [{"ipdst":"192.168.1.1","macdst":"aa:aa:aa","ipsrc":"192.168.1.2",count:1},
{"ipdst":"192.168.1.4","macdst":"cc:cc:cc","ipsrc":"192.168.1.5",count:1},{"ipdst":"192.168.1.1","macdst":"aa:aa:aa","ipsrc":"192.168.1.2",count:2},{"ipdst":"192.168.1.4","macdst":"cc:cc:cc","ipsrc":"192.168.1.5",count:1}]
```

I expected the output to be

```
{"ipdst":"192.168.1.4","macdst":"cc:cc:cc","ipsrc":"192.168.1.5",count:2"}
```

(for a destination that sent 2 packet to the source)

How can I do this?

Comment: What are the values of dst, mac and src?

Comment: To fix what? I don't see any error.

Comment: @DanielMesejo I get the value from sniffing the packet using scapy and i put it the ip dst,  mac dst and ip src to the list

Comment: @PedroLobito yes there is no error but the output is not like what i want.  Thats why im asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of looping over all of the items in the dictionary each time you get a new packet, you can use a dictionary to keep track of the count of each destination + source + mac.

```
counts = {}
```

And then whenever you get a new item, you would simply need to increment the corresponding value in the counts dictionary, and you'll have your item's count.

```
dst_src_mac = item["ipdst"] + item["macdst"] + item["ipsrc"]
if (dst_src_mac in counts):
    counts[dst_src_mac] += 1
else:
    counts[dst_src_mac] = 1

item['count'] = counts[dst_src_mac]
```